# Calling API with parameter from state

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, react-query

I have simple component like this, that is fetching data from url, based on parameter passed in router.

```
const HelloComponent = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  const {isLoading, error, data} = useQuery("myQuery", () => axios.get("/api/something/" + location.state.id))

  return (<>Hello world</>)
}
```

Back to parent component, I just have something like this

```
        <Link to={"/something"} state={{id: "myId"}}>
          ....
        </Link>
```

The problem is, API is having 2 GET methods, first for just `/GET/api/something`, that returns list of "somethings", and another one for `/GET/api/something/{id}` that returns something with specified ID. The problem I have with `HelloComponent` is that, it starts calling API before it gets `location.state.id`, so it is basically calling API to get list of elements, not single element with given ID. How can I prevent it from happening and force `useQuery` to wait for `location.state.id` to be initialized?

Answer (score 1):

looking from the docs here: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/disabling-queries?from=reactQueryV3&original=https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/guides/disabling-queries

I guess you should disable the auto fetching by default, only once enable it when the location.state.id is ready.

```js
const {
  isLoading,
  error,
  data,
} = useQuery(
  ["myQuery", location.state.id],
  () => axios.get(`/api/something/${location.state.id}`),
  { enabled: !!location.state.id }
);
```

Comment: Even hardcoded `{enabled: false}` is not stopping any API calls